# OWIN middleware for Multi-Tenant Web App

Tags: c#, authentication, authorization, owin

I'm starting the development process for my multi-tenant web app and now I'm trying to see find frameworks and test them in order to not rebuild the wheel... For a very long time now I've been on maintance duty of a quite old legacy software and now I'm getting familiar to MVC 5 and etc... right now I'm looking into OWIN Authentication-Authorization and I would like to know if anyone see a issue that would cause to be deemed "inadequate" for the following scenario:

> My App has 6 main types of users:
>
> - Platform Admin (for now, me, the developer)
> - Tenant Owner (this is the guy whose credit card i will bill, basically the owner of the print shop)
> - Tenant User (these are the shop employees)
> - **User** (think this as the main contact on the client enterprise, like the Marketing Manager, OR a given random client not attached to any enterprise, anyway, **this is the guy who the print shop will bill**)
> - Client User (the marketing dpt staff that sends stuff to be printed)
> - Anonymous User

I dont want to handle passwords and etc, so i think i will only allow facebook/gmail/yahoo/etc login and registration. So I belive I got authentication covered. But authorization-wide I'm not so sure, see this is a multi-tenant app so a given **login** may be the Tenant Owner for Shop01, User for Shop02 and Client User for Shop02 AND Shop03 (in this case the person could print in his own bill, or the company's)... I don't think `[Authorize]` will be flexible enough...

Now back to my question: is this scenario feasible to cover using OWIN Authentication-Authorization or is there a more suitable framework?!?

**Edit1:** Tapping on some experience, I think something more Access Control List oriented might suit me better... specially because different tenants might have different roles for their employees (maybe a Tenant Finances User that will only be able to handle payments and wont be able to see whatever a client is uploading...)

Comment: Could you use roles? Have one for "platform admin," "tenant owner," tenant user," etc.? As you said, that could help avoid reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen edited: see edit1... I don't think fixed roles will be a way... I have talked to a 3 possible tenants, and they all described a different "sales clerk" in terms of permission (one would be able to issue refunds, another would be able only to see a given client balance and the third would only be able to update a order to "delivered"...)

Comment: fair enough, although if I were writing this I'd probably still use roles. You could have "SalesClerk_Alpha," "SalesClerk_Bravo," "SalesClerk_Charlie" if need be. I'm definitely with you that it isn't the prettiest solution, but as far as I know ASP only offers inherent support for a single layer of user grouping or abstraction. And I bet the un-pretty solution of roles like this would be more stable than most other options. It'd be kind of like the Windows FS roles, where you have "Admins" but you also specify different *types* of admins with different access grants.